# RelativeLayout in a ListView

Tags: android

I am having trouble getting a RelativeLayout to work within a ListView. If I change the layout to linear etc. I see it behave as I would expect but the RelativeLayout is scrunching everything up into overlapping space. Now my uneducated guess is that it is trying to cram everything into on row. I thought it would expand that row but perhaps not or that is not the problem.

Note my code has been abbreviated for space.

Anyway in my Parent XML:

```
<LinearLayout ..._width="fill_parent" ..._height="fill_parent" ...orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView ...layout_width="fill_parent" ...layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So my thought was that this would fill the device screen and in the GraphicalLayout view in Eclipse it appears that it does.

My "row" definition for the ListView is this:

```
<RelativeLayout width="fill_parent" height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
       android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
      .....
</RelativeLayout>
```

As mentioned I thought this would fill all available space but it seems to only fill some sort of "default" row height?

What am I missing?

Comment: see this tuts http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding the getView of the ArrayAdapter and then setting the height and width to the dynamically determined screen size

...snip....

```
int[] iarry_ScrnDim = new int[2];

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
metrics = ctx_Currnt.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

iarry_ScrnDim[0] = metrics.heightPixels;
iarry_ScrnDim[1] = metrics.widthPixels;

return iarry_ScrnDim;
```

....snip....

```
if (vw_BigRow == null)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vw_BigRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.liftdatalayout, null);
}

vw_BigRow.setMinimumHeight(mHeight);
vw_BigRow.setMinimumWidth(mWidth);
```

Answer (score 2):

use the layout attributes `layout-above`, `layout-below`, `layout-toRightOf`, `layout-toLeftOf` in your xml. that way the items will be put next to where you want them to go. right now you are setting everything according to the parent so they are all going to overlap

Comment: OHHH don't I feel dumb. Yes that's it exactly.

Comment: I guess I don't have it figured out. I added layout_alignParentBottom="true" and layout_alignParentRight="true" to an element that should be at the bottom and it isn't. Still all crammed together like trying to fit in one row. If I set the ListView "row" XML RelativeLayout to minheight of 500dp everything spreads out so I'm back to thinking there is some sort of default row heinght for the listView that is constraining it.

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeLayout` by default adds it's children anchored to the top left corner of the layout.

By using the very handy attributes of `RelativeLayout`, you can arrange the children both

- relatively to each other, and
- relatively to the parent view.

`layout_alignParentLeft`, `..Right`, `..Top`, `..Bottom`, `layout_centerInParent`, `layout_centerHorizontal`, `layout_centerVertical`, `layout_toLeftOf`, `..toRightOf`, `..above`, `..below`

These attributes will help you get the desired display in a very efficient (flat) way, so I'd suggest keep reading it up and consider using it instead of other layout containers for complex views.